# Recursively transform json in play

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I have the following `json` that I need to transform in two ways:

1. rename `val` to value
2. remove `id` field.

My code

```
val tmp=new String ("[{"id":3,"date":"1969-07-20","val":4}, {"id":4,"date":"1944-07-20","val":5}]")
```

I thought of using `prune` and `copyValue` transformations but I understood they do not work with recursive `JsPath`.

I appreciate help with that.

Comment: `val tmp = new String(...)` is redundant. You can just write `val tmp = "......."`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to parse your JSON as a pure String, you can do something simple with `replace`:

```
val tmp= """[{"id":3,"date":"1969-07-20","val":4}, {"id":4,"date":"1944-07-20","val":5}]"""

tmp.replaceAll("\"val\"", "\"value\"").replaceAll("\"id\"[^,]*,", "")
// [{"date":"1969-07-20","value":4}, {"date":"1944-07-20","value":5}]
```

This isn't ideal and as is written only works if `id` is followed by a comma, but you get the picture. You can do a Regex match with `replaceAll` and replace what you find with the expected result.

---

A better, preferred way (in my opinion) is to manipulate the JSON as a JsObject and use case classes to store it.

Say you have the following JSON:

```
val jamesAsJson: JsObject = Json.obj("name" -> "james", "age" -> 34)
// jamesAsJson: play.api.libs.json.JsObject = {"name":"james","age":34}
```

You can map this to a `case class` which has a corresponding `object` containing some JSON-y magic in it like this:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

object Person {
  // This is magic. Don't worry about how it works
  implicit val format: OFormat[Person] = Json.format[Person] 
}

// I know this JSON matches my case class but if you're unsure,
// you should use getOrElse otherwise it'll throw an Exception
val jamesAsPerson = jamesAsJson.validate[Person].get
// jamesAsPerson: Person = Person(james,34)
```

Next, you can create another case class with the new fields you want and pop this old data into your new case class:

```
case class AltPerson(fullName: String, age: Int)

object AltPerson {
  implicit val format: OFormat[AltPerson] = Json.format[AltPerson]
}

val jamesAsAltPerson = AltPerson(jamesAsPerson.name, jamesAsPerson.age)

val jamesAsAltJson = Json.toJson(jamesAsAltPerson)
// jamesAsAltJson: play.api.libs.json.JsObject = {"fullName":"james","age":34}
```

So that's one way to change your field names. There are hundreds of ways to do something in Scala; this is just one. Another way could be to read the JSON as a String, do a `replaceAll` on the `key` you want to change, and then parse it as a JSON Object for the next stage...

Once you're happy with your JSON keys, manipulating JsObject fields is very easy. Using our example before, it's as simple as this:

```
jamesAsAltJson - "age"
// res0: play.api.libs.json.JsObject = {"fullName":"james"}
```

This can be carried on for as long as you want:

```
jamesAsAltJson - "age" + ("height" -> JsString("234")) + ("eye colour" -> JsString("blue"))
// res1: play.api.libs.json.JsObject = {"fullName":"james","height":"234","eye colour":"blue"}
```

---

Finally, your example contains an array which makes things a little more complex but here is how you could do it using Scala Play's JSON parser:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
// import play.api.libs.json._

val tmp = """[{"id":3,"date":"1969-07-20","val":4}, {"id":4,"date":"1944-07-20","val":5}]"""
// tmp: String = [{"id":3,"date":"1969-07-20","val":4}, {"id":4,"date":"1944-07-20","val":5}]

case class Tmp(id: Int, date: String, `val`: Int)
// defined class Tmp

object Tmp {
    implicit val format: OFormat[Tmp] = Json.format[Tmp]
}
// defined module Tmp

val tmpAsClass = Json.parse(tmp).as[Seq[Tmp]]
// tmpAsClass: Seq[Tmp] = List(Tmp(3,1969-07-20,4), Tmp(4,1944-07-20,5))

case class NewTmp(id: Int, date: String, value: Int)
// defined class NewTmp

object NewTmp {
  implicit val format: OFormat[NewTmp] = Json.format[NewTmp]
}
// defined module NewTmp

val newTmp = tmpAsClass.map(x => NewTmp(x.id, x.date, x.`val`))
// newTmp: Seq[NewTmp] = List(NewTmp(3,1969-07-20,4), NewTmp(4,1944-07-20,5))

// JsArray is annoying to work with so I've used List[JsObject] instead
val jsonList: List[JsObject] = Json.toJson(newTmp).as[List[JsObject]].map(_ - "id")
// jsonList: List[play.api.libs.json.JsObject] = List({"date":"1969-07-20","value":4}, {"date":"1944-07-20","value":5})

Json.toJson(jsonList)
// res0: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = [{"date":"1969-07-20","value":4},{"date":"1944-07-20","value":5}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You **must** keep in mind that you are working with a Json parser that generates an abstract syntax tree of Json documents, and converts into JsValue representing the Json document. For the same reason you can't change the name of a variable of a class (except you rewrite it) you can't change val to value as well.

However, I see you are trying to represent your code as string here instead of doing this:

```
val json:JsValue = Json.parse("""
  {
    "arrayObjects" : [{"id":3,"date":"1969-07-20","val":4}, {"id":4,"date":"1944-07-20","val":5}]
  } 
""")
```

If this isn't your intention, then you don't need play-json. You can find a simple solution to your problem by simply manipulating the string.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if the `tmp` is a of type String (reminder: use `"""` to be compilable), you can just use `.replace` on it:

```
scala> val tmp=new String ("""[{"id":3,"date":"1969-07-20","val":4}, {"id":4,"date":"1944-07-20","val":5}]""")
tmp: String = [{"id":3,"date":"1969-07-20","val":4}, {"id":4,"date":"1944-07-20","val":5}]

scala> tmp.replace("val","whatever") 
res0: String = [{"id":3,"date":"1969-07-20","whatever":4}, {"id":4,"date":"1944-07-20","whatever":5}]
```

**Another Approach Using Case Classes**

I generally like to avoid String manipulation as much as possible. What about this approach:

1. Have a two different case classes. One that mirrors the Json you provided. And, second a case class that you want to transform into.
2. You use Json read and transforming it into the first case class. You end up with a list of this class.
3. You map through it and drop the `id` (as the second case class does not have it); and move the value of `val`; into the value of the `value` in the second case class.